# how do I put multiple values into a combo box without the separating character appearing?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, text-files, streamreader

i'm trying to add data to a combo box, i'm adding an ID and a name, with both appearing on the same line. I'm using ~ to seperate the names and IDs. However I can't figure out how to put these values into a combobox without also adding the ~

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("nameForSkiTimes.txt");
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        addSkiTimesPupilCB.Items.Add(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
}
```

I don't really know how to do much in c#, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your data are delimited with a "~", the easiest way to separate them is using the Split method. Split return an array of strings with the elements (in your case, the ID and the name)

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("nameForSkiTimes.txt");
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    string[] data;
    string label;

    while (line != null)
    {
        data = line.Split("~"); // split on "~" char
        if (data.Length > 1) // check if we have at least two elements
        {
            label = $"{data[0]} {data[1]}"; // Access your ID and your name with index, format as you wish
            addSkiTimesPupilCB.Items.Add(label);
        }
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like it short:

In the function, you simply replace this special character with nothing.

```
try 
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("nameForSkiTimes.txt");
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null) 
    {
        addSkiTimesPupilCB.Items.Add(line.Replace("~", ""));
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is to learn working with files and streams a better solution is to use a json file and deserialize with Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json.

[image]

Sample json, in this case named People.json residing in the same folder as the app.

```
[
  {
    "Identifier": 1,
    "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste"
  },
  {
    "Identifier": 2,
    "Name": "Die Wandernde Kuh"
  },
  {
    "Identifier": 3,
    "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese"
  },
  {
    "Identifier": 4,
    "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería"
  },
  {
    "Identifier": 5,
    "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquerí"
  }
]
```

Class for json

```
public class Person
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize json to a list of Person and assign the ComboBox. A Button to get the currently selected Person in the ComboBox.

```
public partial class JsonToComboBoxForm : Form
{
    public JsonToComboBoxForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = 
            Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, 
                "People.json");

        var json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        
        PeopleComboBox.DataSource = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
    }

    private void CurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person current = (Person)PeopleComboBox.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show($@"{current.Identifier, -5}{current.Name}");
    }
}
```

Or to display both Identifier and Name

[image]

```
public class Person
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => $"{Identifier} - {Name}";
}
```